# NestJS Standalone app can't inject Sequelize instance using connection token

Tags: dependency-injection, sequelize.js, nestjs, sequelize-typescript

I'm still quite new to NestJS. I'm trying to implement a standalone app that connect to both external/remote source DB and the app DB.

Now I got stuck at `Nest can't resolve dependencies of the SourceDbQueryService (ModuleRef, ?). Please make sure that the argument {{token}} at index [1] is available in the EtlModule context.`

The `{{token}}` here is supposedly a string returned from `getConnectionToken(connectionName)`, ex.: `sourceDbConnection` when connectionName = `sourceDb`

Here are my modules setup example:

#### /src/db/source-db-module.ts

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        ConfigModule,
        LoggingModule,
        SequelizeModule.forRootAsync({
            imports: [ConfigModule],
            inject: [SourceDbConfig],
            useFactory: (config: SourceDbConfig) => {
                return {
                    ...config,
                    name: SourceDbConfig.DefaultConnectionName,
                    autoLoadModels: false,
                }
            },
        }),
    ],
    exports: [SequelizeModule],
})
export class SourceDbModule {}
```

#### /src/jobs/etl-module.ts

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        ConfigModule,
        LocalDbModule,
        /** Contains Local repositories with decorated Models, using connection from LocalDbModule */
        RepositoryModule,
        SourceDbModule,
        SequelizeModule.forFeature([], SourceDbConfig.DefaultConnectionName),
    ],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: SourceDbQueryService,
            inject: [ModuleRef, getConnectionToken(SourceDbConfig.DefaultConnectionName)],
            useFactory(moduleRef: ModuleRef, sequelize: Sequelize) {
                return new SourceDbQueryService(moduleRef, sequelize)
            },
        },
    ],
    exports: [SourceDbQueryService],
})
export class EtlModule {}
```

### /src/jobs/test-query-source-db.ts

```
async function bootstrap(): Promise<void> {
    try {
        const appContext = await NestFactory.createApplicationContext(EtlModule)
        appContext.init()

        const sourceDb = appContext.get(SourceDbQueryService)
        const totalRecordsCount = await sourceDb.count({
            // ...filters,
        })
        console.log(
            `retrieved source DB results: (total items: ${totalItemsCount})`
        )

        appContext.close()
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
        process.exit(-1)
    }
}
bootstrap()
```

Please help, what am I missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### Update: Workaround

For now I'm using a workaround by providing Sequelize instance directly from my own factory like this:

##### /src/db/source-db-module.ts

```js
@Module({
    imports: [
        ConfigModule,
        LoggingModule,
    ],
    providers: [
        // WORKAROUND: For SequelizeModule.forRootAsync() injection by connection token not working
        {
            provide: getConnectionToken(SourceDbConfig.DefaultConnectionName),
            inject: [SourceDbConfig],
            useFactory(config: SourceDbConfig) {
                const { host, port, username, password, database, dialect } = config

                return new Sequelize({
                    host,
                    port,
                    username,
                    password,
                    database,
                    dialect,
                })
            },
        },
        {
            provide: SourceDbQueryService,
            inject: [ModuleRef, SourceDbConfig, getConnectionToken(SourceDbConfig.DefaultConnectionName)],
            useFactory(moduleRef: ModuleRef, config: SourceDbConfig, sequelize: Sequelize) {
                const { schema, viewName } = config
                return new SourceDbQueryService(moduleRef, sequelize, { schema, viewName })
            },
        },
    ],
    exports: [
        getConnectionToken(SourceDbConfig.DefaultConnectionName),
        SourceDbQueryService,
    ],
})
export class SourceDbModule {}
```

##### /src/jobs/etl-module.ts

```js
@Module({
    imports: [
        ConfigModule,
        LocalDbModule,
        /** Contains Local repositories with decorated Models, using connection from LocalDbModule */
        RepositoryModule,
        SourceDbModule,
    ],
})
export class EtlModule {}
```